# What problems can be expected using D1 and dlls?

Tags: dll, d, dmd

What problems can I expect using a dll compiled using dmd compiler (D1) if c++ program calls that dll and that c++ program is multithreaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D uses a [stop-the-world garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Stop-the-world_vs._incremental_vs._concurrenthttp://), which means that it needs to be able to pause all threads that access D-managed memory during a collection. In order to do that, the runtime must have a list of these threads.

The D2 guideline for [Writing Win32 DLLs in D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/dll.html) has instructions on adding DLL_THREAD_ATTACH/DLL_THREAD_DETACH handlers to notify the runtime of new threads, however [the D1 version of the article](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/dll.html) only mentions that "Multiple threads not supported yet". Thus, if you're forced to use D1, you will probably have to synchronize all of your DLL's entry points (exported functions) using a global lock, or somehow else take care of the synchronization.